# HA VPN implementation between projects owned by different organisations

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm almost blocked on HA VPN implementation between my project and a project owned by a different party. HA VPN implementation ( Both the peers are Google HA VPN ) requires access to the peer VPN networking details. Unlike classic VPN where we simply need to provide the external IP of peer VPN. My peer VPN GCP project owner has denied my access to his VPC networking info. Also tried mentioning peer VPN as on-prem or non Google owned VPN in HA-VPN configuration. However this failed as my peer VPN external IP was owned by Google.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help/on-topic] about what's on-topic. This site is about software programming, not about networking.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#ha-requirements), HA VPN rejects Google Cloud IP addresses when they are configured in an external VPN gateway resource—for example, using the external IP address of a VM instance as the external IP address for the external VPN gateway resource. The only supported HA VPN topology between Google Cloud networks is where HA VPN is used on both sides, as documented in [Creating an HA VPN between Google Cloud networks](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-ha-vpn2). If you want to connect to an HA VPN gateway that resides in a Google Cloud organization or project that you don't own, request the compute.vpnGateways.use [permission](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/creating-ha-vpn2#managing_permissions) from the owner.

Comment: Shall try this approach :
Requesting compute.vpnGateways.use permission on the Peer GCP project